# How to open selected files (all files) from favorites in Intellij Idea (2017)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-organization, favorites

I am working on a huge project in IntelliJ and I am using "Favorites" tab to organize the parts of project I am working on so I do not have to navigate in Project view, because it is a mess. Sometimes I need to open all my favorites files (from one folder in favorites) or selected few at once but I did not find the way to do that. I tried to look online but without success. I know its not that time consuming but at this point I am more curious if its possible.

Anyone know how to do it? Or alternatively how to organize my files within the project view while obscuring files I dont need effectively?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the files you need to open in the Favorites view with the mouse while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (for range selection) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (for individual items), then press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: Wow and I thought I tried everything, thank you very much!